# Add margin when next item has class with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title">TITLE: Kausalya</h2>
    <p class="content">CONTENT: Shaunaka Shakha</p>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title">TITLE: Kausalya</h2>
    <span class="author">AUTHOR: Ayuidasht</span>
    <p class="content">CONTENT: Shaunaka Shakha</p>
</div>
```

I can do this with jQuery, but how can I do this with css?

```
$('.title').next('.content').css('margin-top','20px');
```

I just need a margin-top on the content if it comes after a title. i know I can do this with css but i forgot how and I cant figure out what it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jMc25/)

```
.title + .content {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h2 + p{
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Thanks. that is what I wanted to. is it a selector or combintor? im confused. you and josh called it different things.

Comment: @kausalya it's a *Selector*